# Errors on adding ActionBarSherlock as library to android project

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I've been trying to actionbarsherlock with google maps. Following this youtube link(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k), I've managed to add it as a library to my android project. However, after adding, I got errors like below, and my R.java file got removed.

```
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarSize'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:48: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:50: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarTabBarStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:49: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarTabStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarTabTextStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionButtonStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionDropDownStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:54: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionMenuTextAppearance'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:55: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionMenuTextColor'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeBackground'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:58: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:59: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionOverflowButtonStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:61: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:popupMenuStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:62: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:selectableItemBackground'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:63: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:64: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Spinner.DropDown'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:89: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:90: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:91: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.ListPopupWindow'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:92: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:102: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.PopupMenu'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:94: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:140: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarSize'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:141: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarTabBarStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:142: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarTabStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:144: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarTabTextStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:145: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionButtonStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:146: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionDropDownStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:147: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionMenuTextAppearance'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:148: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionMenuTextColor'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:149: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeBackground'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:150: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:151: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:152: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionOverflowButtonStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:popupMenuStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:selectableItemBackground'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:180: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:183: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:191: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Spinner.DropDown'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:181: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:184: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.ListPopupWindow'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:185: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.PopupMenu'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:186: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:67: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:customNavigationLayout'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:displayOptions'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:homeLayout'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:75: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:indeterminateProgressStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:76: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:itemPadding'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:77: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:logo'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:78: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:navigationMode'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:progressBarPadding'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:subtitle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:subtitleTextStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:titleTextStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:160: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:162: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:customNavigationLayout'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:163: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:displayOptions'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:166: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:homeLayout'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:168: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:indeterminateProgressStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:169: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:itemPadding'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:170: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:logo'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:171: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:navigationMode'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:174: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:progressBarPadding'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:176: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:subtitle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:177: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:subtitleTextStyle'.
[2012-07-18 15:26:46 - SRD-Android] C:\Users\consprice\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.4.0-0-g38eb59b\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-0a25f34\library\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:173: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:titleTextStyle'.
```

The android app is using Google APIs 8. The library project is built using Google API 15. I've also added the plugin for the maps but I've got errors as such:

`The type com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock$OnCreatePanelMenuListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

I'm guessing it's due to the errors when from the library. Anyone can provide some help?

Edit (project properties)

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8
android.library.reference.1=../../Downloads/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-4.0.0-0-g422d546/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-df676ad/library
```

Comment: Have you set the build target to the one recommended by the ABS?

Comment: @Chinaski I'm using ABS 4.0.0 and google apis 4.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of things you need to do:

1- Set your build target to API level 14 at least.

2- In your manifest add:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
```

Comment: Hi, after cleaning the project the problems resurfaced. The R.java is still removed and the errors are still there

Comment: The library project itself doesn't have any errors. The only errors I got are the ones posted in the question

Comment: The R file is not being generated because android resource files are missing. This could only mean there is a problem with the build target. Post your project.properties.

Comment: You're still using api level 8. Target shoud be: target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:15 (or at least 14)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the guiding me and your patience:)

Comment: @Benito had the answer that solved my issue. I edited the project.properties file, then cleaned my projects.